# using insert delayed on duplicate update low_priority all together

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want a mysql statement that will insert or update but using the low priority or delayed. This doesn't seem to be working

```
INSERT DELAYED INTO lastaccess
            (x, y, timeaccess)
            VALUES (2, 4, 1309622646)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY timeaccess = 1309622646
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" statement.  This does not work with the `INSERT DELAYED` statement, as per the documentation:

> INSERT DELAYED should be used only for INSERT statements that specify value lists. The server ignores DELAYED for INSERT ... SELECT or INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html